# What are best authentication patterns in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, authentication, basic-authentication

We are using Basic Authentication, when calling our rest services. Once the login service returns success, we are saving 3 variables in cookies. One cookie consists of 'isuserlogged' boolean, 2nd cookie consists of user credentials in encoded format and 3rd cookie consists of user data like name, email. I am using these variables to maintain the state of the user on refresh. IS this a good practice? If not what changes should I make?

Comment: I suggest you do some research before asking questions on SO. https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=angularjs%20authentication

Comment: I believe I have made enough research on this topic and implemented this. But I want to know if there are any better patterns than this..